# Crystal reports expand detail option

Tags: layout, crystal-reports

I am working on crystal reports and I need to know how to create the layout for the below issue:

I have a report as shown below

```
EmpNo    EmpName    Salary
101      Mark       $10000
102      Jain        $8000
```

My client is requesting an option to expand the salary which will show the detailed view of salary amount. something like, each salary amount will have Basic, DA, incentive, Tax, etc.

Is there any option we have to achieve this request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Create a boolean parameter to hide/show Details section named 'Hide Details'.
- Group by the report by EmpNo
- Create a suppression formula for the the Details section that reads:

  //suppress the section if the parameter's value is true
  {?Hide Details}